# Change Printer Display Name on Windows XP

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file, windows-xp

How to change a printers' display name (to make more sense as oppose to HP officejet 76467) using a batch/VBScript file for a network printer in Windows XP?

Comment: Referring to your 2nd question, `logon script` is the best way to deploy printers within a Windows domain.

Comment: @adi Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a site for programming questions. The second question you had in your post is best asked on our sister site, [SU].

Answer (score 1):

We add network printers using a vb script on the root of C:\ and a statement in the run command hklm to run that script. This by passes  users settings.
The script looks like this. I just don't know how to set the second printer as default, if the 1st is offline temporarily.

My labs use the following vbs on log in.

```
' PrinterSetDefault.vbs - Windows Logon Script.
' VBScript - Set Default Printer
' -----------------------------------------------------------' 
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork, strUNCPrinter1, strUNCPrinter2
WScript.Sleep 1000*10*3
strUNCPrinter1 = "\\wopq\wp-b351-1"
strUNCPrinter2 = "\\wopq\wp-b351-2"
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection strUNCPrinter1
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection strUNCPrinter2
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter strUNCPrinter1

WScript.Quit

' End of set printer script.
```

This work beatifully until the default printer goes offline. Then it fails. Looks like I need another line that if strUNCPrinter1 goes offline to send jobs to number 2.
Do you know how I would achieve that?

Thanks
Wayne Turcotte
Algonquin College
Ottawa Canada